# Wierd issue when using nouveau drivers

Tags: linux, kali-linux, nvidia, nouveau, parrotsec

So I recently purchased an Asus rog g531gt and I tried installing latest Kali kde and parrot kde is on it. So the system works fine when I turn off the nouveau drivers in the grub. But I don't do that the system hangs after a while. I tried installing official Linux drivers for my gtx 1650 gpu but it broke my install multiple times. I was only successful in installing Nvidia drivers in Linux mint. So what should I do cause I need gpu for bruteforcing.
Specs :
Intel i5 9300h 
Gtx 1650 
Ram 8gb ddr4
Ssd 512gigs

Comment: Did you install the drivers following [these instructions?](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/)

Comment: No i followed this to install the drivers https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. With Linux, and Nvidia drivers especially, it is always better to handle package management via the distros package mananger . You need to follow the directions that the official Kali documentation lays out. Depending on the circumstances it will be easier to start from scratch too.